# Logstash grok patterns for message

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

below is my log line:

```
TPS Memory value: 123532K, 20210525 205953, ProcessInfo, Memory OOS
```

I try to get column "ProcessInfo" as "rulename" in kibana grok debugger but failed with [parse_exception]
patterns below:

```
(?<rulename>(?<=TPS Memory value: \d+K, \d{8} \d{6}, )\w+)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Note: The exception here is that "\d+K" does not fit, I do not want to use "\d {6}K "to match the field, because the number length in this position is not fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, grok does not keep empty captures ([cf. option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-options): `keep_empty_captures` defaults to false).

You can simply use :

```
TPS Memory value: \d+K, \d{8} \d{6}, (?<rulename>\w+)
```

Comment: Your explanation is correct, thank you for your answer!